# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, csv, parsing, nan

I am calling this line:

```
lang_modifiers = [keyw.strip() for keyw in row["language_modifiers"].split("|") if not isinstance(row["language_modifiers"], float)]
```

This seems to work where `row["language_modifiers"]` is a word (`atlas method`, `central`), but not when it comes up as `nan`.

I thought my `if not isinstance(row["language_modifiers"], float)` could catch the time when things come up as `nan` but not the case.

Background: `row["language_modifiers"]` is a cell in a tsv file, and comes up as `nan` when that cell was empty in the tsv being parsed.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? Just so I know. You can test on the 3 test cases I include in the question.

Answer (score 55):

You are right, such errors mostly caused by NaN representing empty cells.
It is common to filter out such data, before applying your further operations, using this idiom on your dataframe df:

```
df_new = df[df['ColumnName'].notnull()]
```

Alternatively, it may be more handy to use `fillna()` method to impute (to replace) `null` values with something default.
E.g. all `null` or `NaN`'s can be replaced with the average value for its column

```
housing['LotArea'] = housing['LotArea'].fillna(housing.mean()['LotArea'])
```

or can be replaced with a value like empty string "" or another default value

```
housing['GarageCond']=housing['GarageCond'].fillna("")
```

Answer (score 5):

You might also use `df = df.dropna(thresh=n)` where `n` is the tolerance. Meaning, it requires **n Non-NA values to not drop the row**

**Mind you, this approach will remove the row**

For example: If you have a dataframe with 5 columns, `df.dropna(thresh=5)` would drop any row that does not have 5 valid, or non-Na values.

In your case you might only want to keep valid rows; if so, you can set the threshold to the number of columns you have.

[pandas documentation on dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)